# Unity Facebook "An access token is required to request this resource."

Tags: unity, facebook

I have installed Facebook SDK 7.6 for Unity 5.3. It is fine with login and logout stuff things but I am having a problem when it comes to use FB.API. I want to be able to fetch players' profile pictures and names for my multiplayer game project. Each client has other's facebook profile id but I cannot use those IDs on Graph API I guess. What is the way of getting such public information using Facebook SDK.

```
FB.API("/" + facebookID + "?fields=name", HttpMethod.GET, OnNameReceived);
```

Comment: are you trying these after hosting the app in server or is it for mobile game?

Comment: @SP. It is a mobile game and those calls are supposed to be done in clients' devices.